# Database: Active and Inactive data in same or separate Tables

Tags: database

I am faced with the scenario of having one table for all my data or
creating a table for my active data and once finished with the data move it to the archive table.

The data to be stored is job information, where there could be around 100 active jobs. This entire list and all information is frequently grabbed and displayed to the screen. It is also changed frequently as jobs progress.

However once a job is finished, it would not require changing, and only need to search through the completed jobs. In real terms there would be few entries (around 2000 a year) in total.

Would the speed improvement with the frequent query of active jobs be much if the past jobs were to be kept in a separate table? or should both active and completed jobs be in the same table with a completed property for simplicity reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends in part on your server, but any well indexed table should have no problem with finding 100 active jobs out of a table of 2000 per year.  I think the overhead of archiving a job would cost more than any benefit that you would see.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the volume you describe shouldn't be decisive for your design. Even if your job-table is designed so that a single record takes up 1 kb, the table would the grow with 2 mb/year. It would take quite a few years for this table to ever grow to something that would significantly impede overall performance on the server.

Instead, as Stuart also says in his answer, you should look at the work in maintaining a historic table: You will need to keep the two tables in sync, design-wise, so that any changes in your current table doesn't break the historic table. You will have to write the script to move the data - and if you ever want to look at both current and historic data, you will have to write queries that unify the two tables.

Alternatively, you can add a bit/bool column, "Active", and switch this bit on and off depending on the employee's status. Or, if you want to make a more advanced solution, add start- and end-dates and build detailed history this way.